# Binding to self in code

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm defining a DataTemplate in code and I want to set the binding to itself.

```
DataTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(MyCustomViewCell));
DataTemplate.SetBinding(MyCustomViewCell.MyCustomProperty, "");
```

The code above doesn't work. You can't use an empty path in that method. The XAML equivalent I usually use is `MyCustomProperty="{Binding}"`. This sets the property to the current `BindingContext` / `DataContext`.

What is the syntax to achieve this in C#?

Comment: I've always used "." as the binding path to refer directly to the context

Comment: @Jason If you post your comment as answer, I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: done, glad it worked for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a "." as the binding path to refer to the BindingContext itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTemplate.SetBinding<YourType>(MyCustomViewCell.MyCustomProperty, x => x.PropertyOfYourType);
```

Comment: This doesn't work without also specifying the type, but the comment by @Jason seems a better solution.